# How to access comments repository by post

Tags: php, symfony4

I have `OneToMany` relation between Post and Comment entities.

Now I can easily access comments of a post by using `$post->getComments()`.

I want to know how can I get these comments ordered in some way or add some custom where conditions to get only specific comments?

I've created a method in `CommentsRepository`:

```
public function findAllOrdered()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

Is there a possibility to access this method?

I've tried to access it like this: `$post->getComments()->findAllOrdered();`, I know that it does not have much sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to access it from your Controller

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Comment;

public function listComments()
{
    $comments = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Comment::class)
        ->findAllOrdered();
}
```

Comment: But then how can I access them while I'm using them like so: `{% for comment in post.getComments() %}` in my twig template?

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz you can pass the comments as a template variable , but You shouldn't. Thats business logic, that should not appear in templates. One solution is to create a new action within a controller and call from your template

Comment: Hmm, yes I could do so, but I want to have some better solution. There has to be something to allow me access these comments via post object.

Comment: Another suggestion, http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: I've also found it right now. So you're sure that it's not possible to do it like I thought to do it - by post object?

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz maybe someone will post a better answer , I've shared what I know :)

Comment: Okay, and then how would you access `listComments` method in your view? Can you show it?

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarzPlease,read the last link I have shared, it explains how this works

Answer (score -1):

```
class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, $class);
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param null $sql
     * @param array $params
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function findAllPostUserCommentEtcWhatEverYouWant($sql = null, $params = [])
    {
        try {
            return $this->em->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql, $params)->fetchAll();
        } catch (DBALException $e) {

        }
        throw new \Exception('');
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function findThis()
    {
        try {
            return $this->findAllPostUserCommentEtcWhatEverYouWant('select .  ..');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function findThat()
    {
        try {
            return $this->findAllPostUserCommentEtcWhatEverYouWant('select .  ..');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }




    /**
     * @Route("/pdo", name="pdo")
     */
    public function pdo(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $result = $em->getRepository(Post::class)->findThat();
        $result = $em->getRepository(Post::class)->findThis();
```

Comment: Even if it seems trivial, please add a short explanation of your code. Code-only answers are rarely helpful to others and are usually deleted.